# How do I fill a new array with n distinct empty arrays, in a concise one-line initialization statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression, fill, one-liner

Here is where I am stuck.   I want to take this statement and revise it in a manner that the empty array I fill (which I surmise might not work with dynamic values), will initialize bucket to the n distinct empty arrays.

How do I do this?   Is there a way to make this fill method behave in the intended manner?

```js
let radix = 10;
let badBucket = [...Array(radix).fill([])];
let goodBucket = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...Array(radix).fill([])]));
badBucket[3].push(33);
goodBucket[3].push(33);
console.log(JSON.stringify(badBucket));
console.log(JSON.stringify(goodBucket));
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: If I were to push an item to bucket[0] like so bucket[0].push(1), the array contents would all have 1 [[10],[10],[10],[10],[10],[10],[10],[10]], which pretty much be undesireable

Comment: Is this one of those scenarios where If fill can accept a callback, I can return a new empty array from the callback, like so...   fill(() => [])   fingers crossed...awww, unfortunately that was not the case as hoped

Comment: Ok, I have successfully reached desired result, with a more verbose one liner, If helpful to others I can post as a separate answer or keep my comment logs in the comments.  If any more concise initialization expression exists than this, please provide a new answer to my comments.

Comment: `const length = 10, bucket = Array.from({ length }).map(() => []);`

Comment: It looks like my callback to map was what I as unsuccessfully trying to pass into fill (where fill can only understand static values of array length)

Comment: If I can relabel the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, I might be able to cut down the character length of my one-line statement....

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian ... It's not about *one-liners* or being this kind of *extra smart* . A practical solution very often is just a good enough balanced compromise in between a straightforward as possible but still readable / maintainable implementation.

Comment: It seems a looping initializer solution would be a little verbose here, the proposed fill  method I proposed much more concise, but of course a map solution like you proposed would be easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
let radix = 10;
let bucket = [...Array(radix)].map(e=>[])
bucket[0].push(1)
console.log(JSON.stringify(bucket));
```

Comment: This is exactly is the shortest length one liner that meets my desire.  Thank you. Now I know which of the two functions (map ,fill) will accept the callback, and corresponding equivalent initialization stements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the callback function of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
let length = 5;
let res = Array.from({length}, _=>[]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for the specific alternate version using underscore object,  this is quite desirable and produces a great readable response,  with an object of 5 length that I can infer is assigned to an empty array.